# Why is the concentration term in van der Waals correction for ideal gas squared?

Tags: ideal-gas, van-der-waals-behavior

In van der Waals correction for ideal gas equation, the pressure term has a correction where concentration term is squared. I saw derivations for this and they say that the concentration is squared because the number of particles at surface and the force exerted by other particles on the particles at surface, both are dependent on the concentration. I don't get this, could someone please explain why this is so mathematically?
Edit- upon reading more, I found that van der waal gave credit to Laplace for coming up with the pressure reduction term being directly proportional to the square of the density. Could you also explain this?

Comment: Intuitively, the rate of molecular interactions leading to vdW cohesion pressure formally follows kinetics of the 2nd order, so the volume is squared.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Try to simulate a real gas as mixture of ideal monomer and dimer gases in equilibrium, shifted strongly toward the monomer. Then write for the mixture the state equation f(p,V)=n(pure monomer)RT,  taking into account the chemical equilibrium.

Comment: By other words, one V is for the absolute deviation being proportional to 1/V, And the other V is for the relative deviation being proportional to 1/V. Twice as much of dimer stored in half volume causes 4 times greater pressure deviation

Comment: See:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70616/why-is-the-pressure-correction-in-the-van-der-waals-equation-proportional-to-n/126525#126525

Comment: Okay I get the explanation, but how does Laplace fall into this picture?

Comment: The links explanation of the cohesive pressure is better, even if I think that formally it is equivalent to the dimer model.